# Use a proxy for ITFoxtec SAML2 Identity access to IDP

Tags: proxy, configuration, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We use the ItFoxtec library for SAML authentication to Azure Active Directory with an application written in C# and the .Net Core 6 framework.
The library works very well, and we have had no problems.

In production, we have to access the server for IdPMetadata and SingleSignOnDestination via a proxy.

We cannot change the server settings and only have to act on the application.

We tried adding this proxy configuration in appsettings.json

"ProxySettings": {
"Address": "server address:port",
"BypassOnLocal": true,
"UseDefaultCredentials": false
},

but it doesn't work.
We can configure the HttpClient service in startup.cs using ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler() but this is available only for named clients.

How can we configure such a proxy so the library can use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a HttpClient name like this:

```
entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrlAsync(httpClientFactory, new Uri(Configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]), httpClientName: "my-http-client-name").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Code from the sample:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L43C81-L43C81